# How to compute smallest non-zero eigenvalue

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

Given a positive semi-definite matrix M I would like to find its smallest non-zero eigenvalue. In python this code looks tempting

```
import numpy as np
(w,v) = np.linalg.eigh(M)
minw = np.amin(w)
if (np.isclose(minw,0) and minw > 0):
    print M, minw
```

Here is an example small input matrix.

```
[ 6  2 -4 -2]
[ 2  6  0 -6]
[-4  0  6  0]
[-2 -6  0  6]
```

Unfortunately if you try this you will get `8.90238403828e-16`.  I don't know in general how to tell if very small numbers are meant to be zero or not.

How can you find the smallest non-zero eigenvalue of a matrix (and be sure it really is non-zero)?

Comment: Do negative eigenvalues exist? Has the matrix full rank? You may want to read about the power method (power iteration). You need the inverse power iteration. What's the background of your matrix?

Comment: @tschm There are no negative eigenvalues for a positive semi-definite matrix .

Comment: ah, didn't read the positive semi-definite. Ah, it wasn't there back then :-)

Comment: What's np?  (I'd guess numpy, but I'd rather not have to guess.)

Comment: @Arnold Show us matrix.

Comment: You can avoid some of the problems by shifting the matrix, e.g. add a multiple of the identity and compute the n smallest eigenvalues using an inverse power iteration. At some point you will need a kind of threshold for what's zero. Sometimes called regularization parameter...

Comment: Is there an arbitrary precision linear algebra library for python? Maybe http://mpmath.org/ ?

Answer (score 1):

First you might want to check that your matrix is invertible. One way to do this is to calculate the determinant with `numpy.linalg.det`. If it isn't invertible, you can project this matrix into the space orthogonal to the kernel. The projected matrix will now be invertible, with the property that the eigenvalue of smallest magnitude will be the smallest (in magnitude) non-zero eigenvalue of the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a floating problem in the function. The solution will depend on the severity of the problem. You can try loop the results and look for the minimum using, for example, the function ([numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)):

```
    np.isclose(a,b)
```

, giving you similarity between two values within a tolerance. It's not a clean solution but it's generally considered a safe comparison. As for the "eigh" code itself perhaps some issue with convergence, but I really can't tell.

Comment: Whether this is safe or not depends on the size of the smallest non-zero eigenvalue I think.

Comment: It does indeed. Only you can tell what the tolerance should be. This is an engineering problem, not math.